# SQL Plus SP2-0306 from CONNECT line in SQL file, same credentials work in batch file

Tags: database, batch-file, sqlplus

SQLPLUS *userID*/*Password*@*DATABASE* @*filename*.sql

works fine,

SQLPLUS @*filename*.sql

with the first line of *filename*.sql being:

CONN *userID*/*Password*@*DATABASE*

even having copy/pasted over the working line of credentials produces SP2-0306: Invalid Option. I cannot find anything related to this that isn't simply incorrect credentials. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Solved, I needed SQLPLUS /nolog @*filename*.sql instead of SQLPLUS @*filename*.sql

Answer (score 1):

SQLPLUS /nolog @filename.sql instead of SQLPLUS @filename.sql